# Is it possible to filter messages inside GetStream Channel?

Tags: getstream-io

For GetStream Chat mobile SDK, is it possible to filter message inside a channel?

My use case would be like

- Get messages **sent by John** in **channel id "X"**
- Get messages with file attachments in **channel id "X"**

Comment: Which platform and language?

Comment: StreamChatClient iOS, Version 2.2.1 with Swift